# How to use different Connection strings for Azure SignalR Service in Function Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, signalr

Alright, so we have multiple signalR services and what we want to do is when our code is deployed, we want the connection string to be picked from our custom configuration file instead of the function App settings.

This is the negotiate function. See the "SignalRConnectionInfo" attribute.

```
[FunctionName("negotiate")]
public IActionResult negotiate(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")]
HttpRequest req,
[SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = HubName, ConnectionStringSetting = **"Cannot pass dynamic connection string here as it requies a constant"**)]
SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo )
{
           
}
```

we tried adding it in Startup.cs

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot config;
       
        builder.Services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(config["SignalrConnectionString"]);
 
    }
}
```

and it does not work this way. as it gives an error

> Invalid host services. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: The following service registrations did not match the expected services:
> [Invalid] ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService, Lifetime: Singleton, ImplementationType: Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.HeartBeat
> Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: provider

So, is there any other way to use it in the function?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Sorry, we weren't able to do this, so at the end we had to keep connection string from app settings D;

Comment: I filed this just now: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33893

Comment: Thanks. Please do post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick connection strings from custom configuration files, you should first add the configuration files as configuration sources.
See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#customizing-configuration-sources

The SignalR Function extension would pick the connection from a fixed location, by default `AzureSignalRConnectionString`, and you can customize it via `ConnectionStringSetting`.

If you have multiple SignalR service instances, you might want to use multiple endpoints support. Currently only `Persistent` service transport type supports multiple SignalR instances, that is, function would establish WebSocket connections with all the SignalR instances and you could customize the routing logic. This behaviour is different to picking one instance at the function startup. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-signalrservice-extension/blob/dev/docs/sharding.md .

If you don't want to connect to all the SignalR instances, you can configure each connection string in one file, and pick one file as the configuration source that would be added at function startup.

Answer (score 0):

so this was resolved over here,
https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/1329#issuecomment-869375720

i am just posting it to answer this question

so basically, in this function ConnectionString can also be a value from the config, here "abc" is the value we are picking.

```
[FunctionName("negotiate")]
public IActionResult negotiate(
 [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")]
 HttpRequest req,
 [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "sync", ConnectionString="abc")] // here is the config value abc which is being picked up from the config file
SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo )
{
   ...       
}
```

and in the connection settings or keyvault

```
{
   "abc":"Endpoint=xxx;AccessKey=xxx;Version=1.0;// here you can put your connectin string
}
```

this doesn't completely answer my question though because i wanted to do it dynamically in the startup file, but it doesn't do that, it still picks from the local.settings.json which i was able to do before as well. but it should suffice for most cases